# After adding next-pwa og:tags not working in next.js

Tags: next.js, workbox, vercel, next-pwa

i just added service-workes to website using next-pwa, all og tags appear as needed but
non of them works :|  I checked it on facebook debugger website and there is 206 response code, also it says that there is not any og tag,
first image is mozila firefox developer tools inspector window, which shows that all og tags are at place as needed
[image]

[image]

[image]

this is my next.config.js file

```
const withPlugins = require('next-compose-plugins')
const withBundleAnalyzer = require('@next/bundle-analyzer')({
  enabled: process.env.ANALYZE === 'true',
})
const withPWA = require("next-pwa")


module.exports = withPlugins([withBundleAnalyzer,withPWA({
  future: {webpack5: true},
  images: {
    domains: [
      "localhost",
      "icito.ge",
      "api.icito.ge",
      "assets.vercel.com",
      "via.placeholder.com",
      "mine-front-new.vercel.app",
    ],
  },
  pwa: {
    dest: "public",
    register: true,
    skipWaiting: true,
    cacheOnFrontEndNav: true,
    fallbacks: {
      image: '/static/images/fallback.png'
    }
  }
})],{
  // future: {
  //   webpack5: true,
  // },
  // images: {
  //   domains: [
  //     "localhost",
  //     "icito.ge",
  //     "api.icito.ge",
  //     "assets.vercel.com",
  //     "via.placeholder.com",
  //     "mine-front-new.vercel.app",
  //   ],
  // },
  // webpack: (config, { dev, isServer }) => {
  //   // config.module.rules.push({
  //   //   test: /\.svg$/,
  //   //   use: ["@svgr/webpack"]
  //   // });
  //   if (!dev && !isServer) {
  //     Object.assign(config.resolve.alias, {
  //       react: "preact/compat",
  //       "react-dom/test-utils": "preact/test-utils",
  //       "react-dom": "preact/compat",
  //     });
  //   }
  //   return config;
  // },
}
);
```

and this is my service-Worker.js:

```
import { skipWaiting, clientsClaim } from 'workbox-core'
import { ExpirationPlugin } from 'workbox-expiration'
import { NetworkOnly, NetworkFirst, CacheFirst, StaleWhileRevalidate } from 'workbox-strategies'
import { registerRoute, setDefaultHandler, setCatchHandler } from 'workbox-routing'
import { matchPrecache, precacheAndRoute, cleanupOutdatedCaches } from 'workbox-precaching'

skipWaiting()
clientsClaim()

// must include following lines when using inject manifest module from workbox
// https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/precache-files/workbox-build#add_an_injection_point
const WB_MANIFEST = self.__WB_MANIFEST
// Precache fallback route and image
WB_MANIFEST.push(
  {
    url: '/fallback',
    revision: '1234567890'
  }
)
precacheAndRoute(WB_MANIFEST)

cleanupOutdatedCaches()
registerRoute(
  '/',
  new NetworkFirst({
    cacheName: 'start-url',
    plugins: [new ExpirationPlugin({ maxEntries: 1, maxAgeSeconds: 86400, purgeOnQuotaError: !0 })]
  }),
  'GET'
)
// registerRoute(
//   /^https:\/\/fonts\.(?:googleapis|gstatic)\.com\/.*/i,
//   new CacheFirst({
//     cacheName: 'google-fonts',
//     plugins: [new ExpirationPlugin({ maxEntries: 4, maxAgeSeconds: 31536e3, purgeOnQuotaError: !0 })]
//   }),
//   'GET'
// )
registerRoute(
  /\.(?:eot|otf|ttc|ttf|woff|woff2|font.css)$/i,
  new StaleWhileRevalidate({
    cacheName: 'static-font-assets',
    plugins: [new ExpirationPlugin({ maxEntries: 4, maxAgeSeconds: 604800, purgeOnQuotaError: !0 })]
  }),
  'GET'
)
// disable image cache, so we could observe the placeholder image when offline
registerRoute(
  /\.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|png|svg|ico|webp)$/i,
  new NetworkFirst({
    cacheName: 'static-image-assets',
    plugins: [new ExpirationPlugin({ maxEntries: 64, maxAgeSeconds: 86400, purgeOnQuotaError: !0 })]
  }),
  'GET'
)
registerRoute(
  /\.(?:js)$/i,
  new StaleWhileRevalidate({
    cacheName: 'static-js-assets',
    plugins: [new ExpirationPlugin({ maxEntries: 62, maxAgeSeconds: 86400, purgeOnQuotaError: !0 })]
  }),
  'GET'
)
registerRoute(
  /\.(?:css|less)$/i,
  new StaleWhileRevalidate({
    cacheName: 'static-style-assets',
    plugins: [new ExpirationPlugin({ maxEntries: 32, maxAgeSeconds: 86400, purgeOnQuotaError: !0 })]
  }),
  'GET'
)
registerRoute(
  /\.(?:json|xml|csv)$/i,
  new NetworkFirst({
    cacheName: 'static-data-assets',
    plugins: [new ExpirationPlugin({ maxEntries: 32, maxAgeSeconds: 86400, purgeOnQuotaError: !0 })]
  }),
  'GET'
)
registerRoute(
  /\/api\/.*$/i,
  new NetworkFirst({
    cacheName: 'apis',
    networkTimeoutSeconds: 10,
    plugins: [new ExpirationPlugin({ maxEntries: 16, maxAgeSeconds: 86400, purgeOnQuotaError: !0 })]
  }),
  'GET'
)
registerRoute(
  /.*/i,
  new NetworkFirst({
    cacheName: 'others',
    networkTimeoutSeconds: 10,
    plugins: [new ExpirationPlugin({ maxEntries: 32, maxAgeSeconds: 86400, purgeOnQuotaError: !0 })]
  }),
  'GET'
)

// following lines gives you control of the offline fallback strategies
// https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/advanced-recipes#comprehensive_fallbacks

// Use a stale-while-revalidate strategy for all other requests.
setDefaultHandler(new StaleWhileRevalidate())

// This "catch" handler is triggered when any of the other routes fail to
// generate a response.
setCatchHandler(({ event }) => {
  // The FALLBACK_URL entries must be added to the cache ahead of time, either
  // via runtime or precaching. If they are precached, then call
  // `matchPrecache(FALLBACK_URL)` (from the `workbox-precaching` package)
  // to get the response from the correct cache.
  //
  // Use event, request, and url to figure out how to respond.
  // One approach would be to use request.destination, see
  // https://medium.com/dev-channel/service-worker-caching-strategies-based-on-request-types-57411dd7652c
  switch (event.request.destination) {
    case 'document':
      // If using precached URLs:
      return matchPrecache('/fallback');
      // return caches.match('/fallback')
      break
    case 'image':
      // If using precached URLs:
      return matchPrecache('/static/images/fallback.svg');
      // return caches.match('/static/images/fallback.png')
      break
    case 'font':
    // If using precached URLs:
    // return matchPrecache(FALLBACK_FONT_URL);
    //return caches.match('/static/fonts/fallback.otf')
    //break
    default:
      // If we don't have a fallback, just return an error response.
      return Response.error()
  }
})
```

Comment: Elaborate your question please. Where have you added these tags? Into `_document.jsx` file? Have you used custom server? What configuration you put in your `next.config.js`? What have you tried so far?

Comment: first image is mozila developer tools inspector window, which shows meta tags inside header, that is dynamic page ( /[id], ) i have not custom server, since nextjs 9.2 i think its not needed as I read, I have nextjs 10.2.0 and this is my config file.... cannot paste here i will add in post